# Thread safe class and object

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Is it always true that, thread safe class always would have a thread safe instance too ?

Please share any example if the statement contradicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class written with thread-safety "mindset" will give thread-safe instances aka objects.

An object is thread-safe if it functions correctly during simultaneous access to his internal state by multiple threads.

By correctly see "maintains correctness" : an object is capable to ensure that all of his invariants are guaranteed even during concurrent access.

Comment: so you mean to say, as long as my class is thread safe, instances actions too are safe ...! Correct ..?

Comment: Yes. What is safe is internal state access..so class (static) and instance (object) variables.